# Is the money made with a pirated/cracked softwere halal for me?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, halal-certification

I decided to create highly informative videos on islam with a pirated / cracked softwere and release them in youtube. In future if I get money from youtube is that going to be **halal** for me?

Comment: Its theft so obviously not halal

Answer (score 1):

That is theft, as you know, which is why you are confused in the first place. At times, the good is separated from the evil so it may be that you will be liable for the theft as a sin, and the good you do is separate. However in this case, it would be surprising if the money will be halal considering that it was initiated by something haram (due to the good being connected directly to the sin, and even occurring only as a result of the sin). I remind you of the following hadith:

> عَنْ أَبِي حَازِمٍ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّ اللَّهَ طَيِّبٌ لاَ
>   يَقْبَلُ إِلاَّ طَيِّبًا -  Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
>   as saying: "O people, Allah is Good and He therefore, accepts only
>   that which is good. ..." (Sahih Muslim).

Comment: I asked a question [Is piracy a form of theft for the purposes of fiqh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35628/17163) which seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks and answered. For others, it may be worthwhile to look at the link above for a deeper analysis.