# Is piracy a sin?

Tags: halal-haram, piracy

Piracy is something that begins with the stage of technology so being something new so we do not pay much attention. Thinking I came to the conclusion that piracy is stealing and stealing, it is a sin that piracy is forbidden, but then when I searched for information on Google, there were different opinions, some said that it is stealing and others that it is not. My question is whether piracy is a sin or not?

Comment: "some said that it is stealing and others that it is not" ... and what do you expect from an answer here that will make it any different from the opinions you have already come across?

Comment: I asked [Is piracy a form of theft for the purposes of fiqh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35628/is-piracy-a-form-of-theft-for-the-purposes-of-fiqh) a while back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalamu alaikum brother, 
First of all I want to say that I am one of the best persons to answer this question. Because before a month I was also a piracy addict. In the beginning I also felt like I am not taking away anything physically so so it won't be considered as stealing but Islam respects copyrights. The thing you are pirating aur purchasing pirated item belongs to someone else and I am sure that he would have tagged it with a price. If you you have that thing in any other way other than paying him by pirating or any other ways it is considered as stealing. And on the day of judgement you will have to you give your good deeds like Salah roja etc. Therefore stop pirating. ( Special note: it applies even when you pirate haram things like pirated movies softwares songs etc) Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but if we break down Piracy, it basically is one person who has legally paid or acquired a product (such as video game/movie) and then distributes it on a platform so others can obtain a copy.

Another reasonable point is that we should follow the laws of country we live in (from an Islamic viewpoint) and if piracy is illegal than we should not take part in it (the actual act which buying and sharing the product which is illegal in the U.S.).

Just to reiterate, I am not qualified to give an answer so I provided some possibly helpful points. Salam.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for your answer.